# Amazon Pinpointを介してアプリキル後も受け取れる通知メッセージを送信できますか？

Tags: aws, firebase, push-notification

react nativeで現在アプリを開発しています。管理画面ではlaravelを使用し、aws-sdk for phpのcreateCanpaignを通して、amazon pinpoint上でキャンペーンを作成し、ios/android共にpush通知を配信するという手法をとっています。この時点ではうまくpush通知をバナーに表示することができていました。しかしここで、androidのアプリキル後、push通知が受け取れなくなることに気づきました。これはアプリを再度起動してフォアグラウンドに置いている時も同様です。　調べたところFCMのpush通知の種類で、アプリキル時に受け取れるものと受け取れないものがあるそうですが、pinpointを介してアプリキル後も受け取れる通知メッセージを送信することは不可能なのでしょうか。素人の知識かつ拙い表現で申し訳ありませんが、どなたか智慧をお貸しください。